# Will I be able to match the paint on peeling cabinets reasonably well?

Tags: cabinets

The paint on the cabinets surrounding our kitchen sink are peeling terribly.  The other cabinets are in reasonably good condition.  We are hoping to remodel the kitchen in the next couple of years, so I don’t want to spend a ton of money repainting/refinishing all of our cabinets.  I would love to just repaint the few that are peeling.

[image]

A few questions regarding how to best go about this:

1. Will A paint shop be able to match the paint color and finish (I.e. semi-gloss? Etc)?
2. Can I sand them by hand?  What grit sand paper should I use?  Will a need to sand all the existing paint off the cabinets that are peeling?  Or just where they are peeling?
3. Should I use a primer?  If so any recommendations?
4. How noticeable will brush marks be?  Should I go the extra mile and rent a spray painter?

Thank you all very much!!

Answer (score 1):

1. Not perfectly, but if you make good choices about which panels to paint it won't be conspicuous.
2. Yes, but I'd limit sanding to the rough edges of the paint left behind after scraping the loose material away. If your cabinets aren't solid wood you risk damaging the veneer and creating a fuzzy appearance.
3. Absolutely. That's the only reliable way to get a good paint bond. Use a high-quality primer with excellent adhesion.
4. That will depend on you. Follow common best practices and it will look just fine. You can also use a foam brush if you don't want any grain at all.

Comment: Agreed, but I wanted to add some thoughts to questions 2 and 4.  2: I wouldn't go any lower then 220, and that is assuming there is a lot of urethane to get through.  300 - 400 would be better for the paint.  You only want to remove enough to get a smooth surface.   4: I would probably just use a foam brush.  Spraying would look much better if you were painting the entire cabinet but for spot applications it's a bit excessive and if you use the wrong needle you may end up with globs of paint.